Built-in Shelves - Cleat Support Question
I am building new shelves for my built-in space. Similar to this. https://imgur.com/a/OFljM0I and https://imgur.com/a/dxP9eRv
My plan is to use 3/4 plywood, a 1x3 or 1x2 trim for the face, hardboard for the bottom, and cleats/spare lumber for supports. I will be painting them.
If I use the 1x3, I can just use 1x2 for the cleats.
1 x 3 = 2.5inches thick/tall
0.75 ply 1.5inch cleat (1x2)
0.25 hardboard
Total = 2.5 inches of material
If I use the 1x2 for the face, I have an inch less and so need to cut down any cleats.
1 x 2 = 1.5 inches thick/tall
0.75 ply 0.5 inch cleat (a 1x2 ripped into 0.5 inch strips)
0.25 hardboard
Total = 1.5 inches of material
My question is this. Does the thickness of the cleat matter, or does it just matter that I am securing the cleats into studs? While the 1x2 would be easiest to use, the shelves may look to thick so I am thinking about using a 1x2.
Any help is appreciated.
Bonus question: Is 3/4 ply overkill for bookshelves, or can I get away with 1/2 inch?
